# Firebase Recycle View is not showing data only blank dull white background in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I following [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbKub4Jss9oWpmtxAPJ_q9Y_W89D6GeYs) Tutorial series on building chat app in android studio and I build a recycle view attached with Firebase database but It's not showing up. You can see in [this image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC6Sh.png) It only shows the area recycle view takes in dull white instead of showing list.

Here is my Firebase database view:
[Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52AOO.png)

Realtime-database image [Realtime-database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko870.png)

Authentication tab image [Authentication data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcG0t.png)

```
// In MainActivity
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("User"); 


// in Register.java
    String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user").child(id);
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference().child("upload").child(id);
```

Here is: **MainActivity.java**: Where Recycle View is Present

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth auth;
RecyclerView UserRecyclerView;
userAdapter adapter;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ArrayList<Users> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("User");
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                // adding data in array
                arrayList.add(users);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Access Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    
    UserRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainUserRecyclerView);
    UserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new userAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
    UserRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Here is: **Adapter as userAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.javamassenger;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class userAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<userAdapter.viewholder>{

Context mainActivity;
ArrayList<Users> arrayList;

public userAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<Users> arrayList) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public userAdapter.viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.users_item, parent,false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull userAdapter.viewholder holder, int position) {


    Users users = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.username.setText(String.valueOf(users.userName));
    holder.status.setText(String.valueOf(users.status));
    Picasso.get().load(users.profilepic).into(holder.circleImageView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}


public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    TextView status, username;

    public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cirImg);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);

    }
}
}
```

If anything else is need to understand problem properly please ask. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is it fine now, or I have cut more code? I am a beginner so I am not that sure which code is responsible for what problem and which is not.

Comment: Does `dataSnapshot` contain any data?

Comment: Yes, it's showing data in Real-time data and Authentication tabs I have added images of those in the question.

Comment: Is this `DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user").child(id);` the reference that you're using to get the users?

Comment: Not to get users but it used as reference.setValue(users) to set users data. users is used as Users users = new Users(id, username, email, pass, imageuri, status). Users is the Users.java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("User");
```

Where your child is called `User`, with capital `U`, while in your database, is written in lowercase:

[image]

To solve this, simply change the starting letter to `u`:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference().child("user");
//
```

Comment: Yes, it works and thank you very much sir. I apologize taking your time for silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your array list which is present as a variable inside your `MainActivity.java`. That update is not noticed by the adapter.

Either make a function inside the adapter which takes that updated array list and updates the list (which is local to the adapter) and then calls `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Or re-initialize your adapter every time your arrayList is updated, which is not a better way to do it. I recommend using the first approach.

Comment: As you said brother, I tried creating a function inside the adapter which takes that updated arrayList and updates it again and I am beginner so I wasn't sure how I should do it, but in userAdapter below in viewholder class, public viewholder, I implemented the same func from MainActivity that is to set dataSnapshot and then notifyDataSetChanged(); but is doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to see the code I can also add image of it as well in the question.

Comment: Did you solved your problem ???

Comment: Yes, It was solved. It was a small Problem of writing capital User instead of user